# undo DOM changes made by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

I have the following code in HTML

```
<div id="page" class="container">
<ul class="textContainer">
    <li>Text one</li>
    <li>Text two</li>
    <li>Text Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I made a bunch of changes in the document through jquery, like adding a bunch of containers around each text and so many other elements...

I want to revert the dom to be like in the initial state when window is resized... I am gonna try the following in jquery

```
var element = $('#page');
var storedElement = element;

//changes will be made here to the dom by some jquery plugin... (adding containers and all)
.......
// on window resize
$window.resize(function() {
   element.remove();
   $('body').append(storedElement); 
});
```

will it work? any other alternatives

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you just set the css property: display: none;?

Comment: At least use replaceWith and use a clone, since you do not save the original, but a named reference to it